# change event is summing value instead of replacing

Tags: jquery

Suppose total amount `50`, I **add** `10` in **vat** input and **minus** `20` from **discount**, correct result -`40` is shown in **grand total**, at first time.

But, if I change `-20` to `-10` in discount input, I mean overriding previous value(`-20`), then result should be `50` but it becomes `30`. It is adding **10 with 20** instead of setting new value `10` and clearing previous `20`,

**After each typed value it is summing new input with previous one, instead of overwrite or replacing.**

Here, for the first time, it is fine

Grand Total **=** `50` **+** `10` = `60` **-** `20` **=** `40`

[image: Correct Result]

Let, retype in discount field, changed `-20` to `-10`, but here it has calculated assuming discount value as `-30`(adding (-20)+(-10)),

**Thus Grand total becomes 30 instead of 50**

[image]

Well, if I set value `0`, the problem will be solved, it will reset, but adding 0 and resetting each time is not user friendlier.

To be more clear, I am generating simple bill system through `Jquery`

First fall each `rate[]` input and `qnt[]` input is multiplied with each other and amount is generated and `val` in `amnt[]` input.

And, discount, vat other condition are applied with `dsc_vat[]`, to total sum of each dynamic `amnt[]`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[name="rate[]"], input[name="qnt[]"]').each(function(){
        var elmnt = $(this);
        $(this).change(function(){
            var qnt = $(this).parents('table').find('input[name="qnt[]"]').val();
            var rte = $(this).parents('table').find('input[name="rate[]"]').val();

            if(qnt > 0 && rte > 0){
                var amnt = qnt*rte;
                $(elmnt).parents('table').find('input[name="amnt[]"]').val(amnt);
                g_ttl();
            }
        })
    })

      $('input[name="dsc_vat[]"]').on("change",function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        var sum = parseInt($(this).parents('table').find('.g_ttl').val());
        if (value!==''){
            if(value[value.length -1]==='%'){
                gttl = ((sum*parseInt(value))/100);    // for percent input
            }
            if(value[value.length -1]!=='%'){
                gttl = parseInt(value);      // for digit input
            }
            $(this).parents('table').find('.g_ttl').val(sum+gttl);
        }
        if (value=='' || value==='0'){
            $(this).val('0');
            g_ttl();
            dsc_vat_each();
        }
    })
})

function g_ttl(){
    var sum = 0;
    $('input[name="amnt[]"]').each(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(value);
        }
        $(this).parents('table').find('.g_ttl').val(sum);
    })
}
function dsc_vat_each(){
  $('input[name="dsc_vat[]"]').each(function(){
    var sum = parseInt($(this).parents('table').find('.g_ttl').val());
    if ($(this).val()!==''){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value[value.length -1]==='%'){
            gttl = ((sum*parseInt(value))/100);
        }
        if(value[value.length -1]!=='%'){
            gttl = parseInt(value);
        }
            $(this).parents('table').find('.g_ttl').val(sum+gttl);
    }
    if ($(this).val()===''){
        $(this).val('0');
        g_ttl();
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='text' value='' name='qnt[]' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' value='' name='rate[]' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' value='' name='amnt[]' disabled /></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan='2'>Vat</th>
        <th><input type='text' value='' name='dsc_vat[]' /></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan='2'>Discount</th>
        <th><input type='text' value='' name='dsc_vat[]' /></th>
      </tr>
      <!-- dsc_vat[] will be add dynamically -->
      <tr>
        <th colspan='2'>Grand Total</th>
        <th><input type='text' value='' class='g_ttl' disabled /></th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is this what you want to happen https://jsfiddle.net/9pox05yu/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, exactly, what I am searching, Thanks man. But why not you post in answer instead of comment.

Comment: Hemant, reason why i posted the answer as a comment is that i have some browser problems that makes it imposible for me to use the snippet tool right now.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.quantity,.rate,.vat, .discount').each(function(){
     $(this).change(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('quantity') || $(this).hasClass('rate')){
            var dataIndex= $(this).data('index');
            var qnt = parseFloat($('.quantity[data-index='+dataIndex+']').val());
            var rate = parseFloat($('.rate[data-index='+dataIndex+']').val());
            var amount=(qnt > 0 ? qnt :0)*(rate>0? rate: 0);
            $('.total[data-index='+dataIndex+']').val(amount);
        }
        var totalAmount=0;
        $('.total').each(function(){
           var total = parseFloat($(this).val());
          totalAmount= totalAmount + (total>0? total : 0)
        })
        var vat = parseFloat($('.vat').val()) ;
        var discount= parseFloat($('.discount').val());
        var grandTotal = totalAmount + (vat>0? vat :0) -(discount>0? discount :0);
        $('.g_ttl').val(grandTotal);
        });
    });    
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='text' value='' name='qnt[]' class="quantity" data-index="0"/></td>
        <td><input type='text' value='' name='rate[]' class="rate"  data-index="0"/></td>
        <td><input type='text' value='' name='amnt[]' class="total"  data-index="0" disabled /></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='text' value='' name='qnt[]' class="quantity" data-index="1"/></td>
        <td><input type='text' value='' name='rate[]' class="rate"  data-index="1"/></td>
        <td><input type='text' value='' name='amnt[]' class="total"  data-index="1" disabled /></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan='2'>Vat</th>
        <th><input type='text' value='' name='dsc_vat[]' class="vat" /></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan='2'>Discount</th>
        <th><input type='text' value='' name='dscount[]' class="discount"/></th>
      </tr>
      <!-- dsc_vat[] will be add dynamically -->
      <tr>
        <th colspan='2'>Grand Total</th>
        <th><input type='text' value='' class='g_ttl' disabled /></th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Check this solution might be help to you.

Comment: Thanks, but your approach is limited for me, first fall all of the rows are added from user side, here I am adding one **Vat** and **Discount** option for the demonstration purpose, so I used `dsc_vat[]` for all rows. So after that, obviously it is not possible to assign  **+** or **-** function for individual class, user assign **-** and **+** as their category nature and their need. So, I think the clean solution is   [link](https://jsfiddle.net/9pox05yu/) by @CarstenLøvboAndersen